# The weight of the tank in Ant-Man?

Tags: analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man

According to the science behind becoming small and large, the sub-atomic distances are shortened or lengthened, and subsequently the small guy has a great density and his punches carry a greater force. By this logic, shouldn't the small tank be at least as heavy as the original, if not far more powerful? Or should not the enlarged ant be so less dense, that it floats in the air!?

Comment: For what it is worth, the tank in the film is a Russian T-34.  They normally weigh ~26 tons.

Comment: I don't see how this is in any way a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: It obviously makes the weight less, otherwise when Ant-Man is on someones shoulder, or running up a gun, that person would have the entire weight of that person on their shoulder/on the gun

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn The problem is that the physics in Ant Man are notoriously bad. Half the time he maintains his mass (so he's really strong) but the other time, he has nearly no mass (so he can walk on people without them noticing)... Without consistency, there's really no way to address any of these questions.