# Shouldn't the building keep its same weight?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, realism, ant-man-and-the-wasp

In the trailer for *Ant-Man and the Wasp*, Hank Pym shrinks a multi-story building to just a few cubic feet. He then wheels it away like luggage. You can see it at the 30 second mark:

The "shrinking" technology works by removing the empty space within and between atoms. So shouldn't the building still weigh many many tons? Is there an in-universe explanation as to how Hank can take it with him?

Comment: Wasn't there also a [tank-pendant someone carried around](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55264/49) at some point? But really, it's the friggin' Ant-Man, we *[already know it doesn't](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/37055/49) make [any sense](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/85941/49)*.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Hey, you even linked to a question that I myself answered! :D

Comment: I believe, pym particles compress both the space between atoms and by displacing part of its mass into another unknown dimension.